# Sabre deeplink for meta searches

Tags: php, soap, sabre

We are building a booking engine that needs to provide xml feed to 3rd parties meta search sites like Skyscanner, CheapFlights etc.

Issue we are having here is that we need to provide a "link"/"deeplink" so that they can land on the exact flights on click through.

What is the best way to achieve this? I cant find a unique flight ID in the BFM request which I can use to do another request to get that single flight when user click on the deeplink.

Has anyone thought of a way to make it happen?

Will be using PHP to code this out.